# How to split a text into multiple object

Tags: crystal-reports

How do I split a datasource into multiple object.

For example, I have a 40-line-text (ex: a variable).

```
Line1
Line2
...
Line40
```

Now on my report page, I have two text object like below :

[image]

Because, object1's height can only be fitted for 20 line of text (the first 20 lines), the remain 20 lines will be "transfered" to object2 :

[image]

Is there any option in crystal report which will allow me to achieve this without coding?